# MySQL: bulk updating in table

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sql-update, updates

I'm using MySQL 5.6 and I have this issue.
I'm trying to improve my bulk update strategy for this case.

I have a table, called *reserved_ids*, provided by an external company, to assign unique IDs to its invoices. There is no other way to make this; I can't use auto_increment fields or simulated sequences.

I have this PL pseudocode to make this assignment:

```
    START TRANSACTION;

OPEN invoice_cursor;

read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH invoice_cursor INTO internalID;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;


    SELECT MIN(SECUENCIAL)
    INTO v_secuencial
    FROM RESERVED_IDS
    WHERE COUNTRY_CODE = p_country_id AND INVOICE_TYPE = p_invoice_type;

    DELETE FROM RESERVED_IDS WHERE SECUENCIAL = v_secuencial;

    UPDATE MY_INVOICE SET RESERVED_ID = v_secuencial WHERE INVOICE_ID = internalID;


END LOOP read_loop;

CLOSE invoice_cursor;

COMMIT;
```

So, it's take one - remove - assign, then take next - remove - assign... and so on.

This works, but it's very very slow.
I don't know if there is any approach to make this assignment in a faster way.
I'm looking for something like *INSERT INTO SELECT...*, but with UPDATE statement, to assign 1000 or 2000 IDs directly, and no one by one.

Please, any suggestion is very helpful for me.
Thanks a lot.

**EDIT 1**: I have added *WHERE* clause details, because it was requested by user @vmachan . In the *UPDATE...INVOICE* clause, I don't filter by other criteria, because I have the direct and indexed invoice ID, which I want to update. Thanks

Comment: Could you post the `WHERE` criteria for selecting from `RESERVED_IDS` and updating the `MY_INVOICE` tables.. ?

Comment: @vmachan , thank you for your answer. I have added SQL details as you requested. I hope the edited question was more clear than before. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have this solution. It's much faster than my initial approach.

The UPDATE query is

```
set @a=0;
set @b=0;


UPDATE MY_INVOICE
INNER JOIN
(
    select 
        F.invoice_id,
        I.secuencial as RESERVED_ID, 
        CONCAT_WS(/* format your final invoice ID */) AS FINAL_MY_INVOICE_NUMBER
    FROM
    (
    select if(@a, @a:=@a+1, @a:=1) as current_row, internal_id
    from MY_INVOICE
    where reserved_id is null
    order by internal_id asc
    limit 2000
    ) F
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT if(@b, @b:=@b+1, @b:=1) as current_row, secuencial
    from reserved_ids
    order by secuencial asc
    limit 2000
    ) I USING (CURRENT_ROW)
) TEMP MY_INVOICE.internal_id=TEMP.INTERNAL_ID
SET MY_INVOICE.RESERVED_ID = TEMP.RESERVED_ID, MY_INVOICE.FINAL_MY_INVOICE_NUMBER=TEMP.FINAL_MY_INVOICE_NUMBER
```

So, with autogenerated and correlated secuencial numbers @a and @b, we can join two different and no related tables like MY_INVOICE and RESERVED_IDs.

If you want to check this solution, please execute this tricky update following these steps:

- Execute @a and then the first inner select in an isolated way: `select if(@a, @a:=@a+1, ...`
- Execute @b and then the second inner select in an isolated way: `select if(@b, @b:=@b+1, ...`
- Execute @a, @b and the big select that builds the TEMP auxiliar table: `select F.invoice_id, ...`
- Execute the UPDATE
- Finally, remove the assigned IDs from RESERVED_ID table.

Assignation time reduced drastically. My initial solution was one by one; with this, you assign 2000 (or more) in one single (ok, and a little tricky) update.

Hope this helps.